# inheritance -- keyword and regular arguments in parent class

Tags: python

If I am doing this right, what is the right way to call an instance of ChildFoo? I ask this because I know that I'm supposed to place arguments before keyword arguments, but don't know what to do in this case...

```
class ParentFoo(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c=None):
        pass

class ChildFoo(ParentFoo):
    def __init__(self,d,e,f=None):
         ParentFoo.__init__(self, a, b, c = "fing")
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? The ParentFoo.__init__ call within ChildFoo.__init__ won't work since neither a, b, nor c are defined in that context (only self, d, e, and f).

Comment: All of this is super clarifying. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ChildFoo` inherit from `ParentFoo` it must get argument also for the parent class

```
class ChildFoo(ParentFoo):
    def __init__(self, a, b, d, e, f=None):
         ParentFoo.__init__(self, a, b, c="fing")
```

I doesn't add 'c' - cause it seems that you want default value when `ChildFoo` init `ParentFoo`. Alternatively, you can supply default values to all the parent arguments

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
class ParentFoo(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c=None):
        print(c)

class ChildFoo(ParentFoo):
    def __init__(self,d,e,f=None):
        super(ChildFoo,self).__init__(d,e,c="fing")

c = ChildFoo("1","2")
```

Official python doc here
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super

Comment: What is 1 and 2 equal to here? Which variables are assigned... are they referring to the parent or child class?

Comment: The 2 parameters are given to the child class, if you want you can pass as positional argumets ( in this instance d and e ). The init of the parent class is done arbitrarily in the super call.